# Firebase not saving data in "for loop" jumps out of loops unexpectedly. possible cause callbacks

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase so I will try to explain as best to my knowledge

***Background***
I am learning javascript and Firebase to develop a webapp. www.frenly.io
(This DB functionality is not deployed to production)
Basic function is to get all the youtube links from profile and list it as a playlist.

Until here everything is good. But everytime when a user reloads the page, the facebook has to be queried for the same link, so I decided to save the links after the first query.

```
function getallLinksFromDB(userID,callback){
        var linksCurrentlyInPlaylist;
        searchForPlaylist(userID,function(result){
            if(result == false){
                callback(false);
            }
            else{
                linksCurrentlyInPlaylist =result;
                // console.log(linksCurrentlyInPlaylist);
                callback(linksCurrentlyInPlaylist);
            }
        });

    }

getallLinksFromDB(userID,function(result){
if(result != false){
songFrom = "DB";
    processSongsForNewFrenDB(userID, newuserName, userPic, result, songFrom, songNum);
    }
}
```

Inside `processSongsForNewFrenDB` function I process the links from DB and show it in a playlist. Also, I have a paging button at the end that fetches new links from facebook as appends it to the playlist.

***Problem***
[This is the fetchNext button that makes a query to FB and fetches video Links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQbQf.png)
The problem occurs when I save links in database the first time, reload the page, and fetch new data from fb then proceed to save new links in database.

Inside `processSongsForNewFrenDB`, there is another function called `processAllLinks`.  after all links are shown in playlist, the links and details are turned into array and fed to another function that will save the links in database. `AddToPlaylist`

This is the full `AddToPlaylist` function

```
function AddToPlaylist(youtubeLinksDetailArray, id, linksArray) {
    var plylstForUser = id + 'default';
    var totalLinks = linksArray.length;
            for (i = 0; i < totalLinks; i++) {

                console.log('saving in linkpool'+i);
                linksPool.child(youtubeLinksDetailArray[i].id).set({
                    'ID': youtubeLinksDetailArray[i].id,
                    'createdTime': youtubeLinksDetailArray[i].created_time,
                    'link': youtubeLinksDetailArray[i].link
                });
                console.log('saving in playlist'+i);
                playlist.child(plylstForUser).child("LinksID").child(linksArray[i]).set({
                    'LinkID': linksArray[i]
                });
            }
}
```

Now the problem here is, the loop runs the first time, but on the second time when its time to save in linksPool table, it jumps out of loop to `searchForPlaylist` line

```
linksCurrentlyInPlaylist =result;
        // console.log(linksCurrentlyInPlaylist);
        callback(linksCurrentlyInPlaylist);
```

I am not sure what is causing this. 
Another thing is if I dont save the value in `linksPool` table and only save it in 
`playlist` table then this behaviour does not happen

My guess is this is likely being caused by improper use of callbacks but if this is the case then I not sure why deleting the

```
linksPool.child(youtubeLinksDetailArray[i].id).set({
                        'ID': youtubeLinksDetailArray[i].id,
                        'createdTime': youtubeLinksDetailArray[i].created_time,
                        'link': youtubeLinksDetailArray[i].link
                    });
```

from `AddToPlaylist` function seems to work

*Any help is appreciated. been stuck with this problem for 2 days.*

Comment: It's really hard to parse what's going on in your code, due to the snippets. Please try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful). This means that you'll start with an empty slate and reproduce the problem without any application logic. At best that will help you find your problem, because you're isolating it. At worst it will give you a perfect snippet of code to share with us.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you for the suggestion. I did what you told and looks like the issue is not with Firebase saving the data, but with `getallLinksFromDB` being called. When I commented that function, the data is saved properly. 
I am still debugging as you suggested. Will update on the finding.

Comment: After more investigation, I have managed to solve this problem. Though I have not been able to solve the root of the problem, at least my data are being saved as they should. 

When the loop broke and went to another function, there was another loop and the counter variable was same "i" so I changed one to "q" and the data was saved properly.